# Append parameter 'form id' with the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code of HTML (Django + Jinja) .

```
<div class="span10 well">

   {% for k in values.chat %}

       <label> Text : {{k.text}} </label> 
       <label> {{k.date_time}} </label>
   {% endfor %}     


   <form action = "#" method = "POST" id = {{key}} name = "reply_form">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type = "submit" value = "Sent" class="btn btn-primary">
   </form>

</div>
```

Since, there will be many chats and correspondingly reply submit button and its key, I want that when I reply to a specific chat, it carries the key with itself and process the chat accordingly.

What I need is to append the url with the form id parameter. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" name="chat_key" value="{{key}}">
```

This way you can track which chatroom the person is responding by setting the value to the id of the chatroom.

EDIT: Since you are using django, on the backend to get the value of the chat_key you can just do this:

```
chat_key = form.cleaned_data['chat_key']
```

Comment: You mean to say inside the `<form>` tags I use this `hidden` input field?

Comment: Is the key that you want to set the value of {{key}}?

Comment: if so then you can just set the value of the hidden field to 
{{key}} with no javascript

Comment: Yes. It's same as the value of {{key}}

Comment: Let me try it out.
Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: I just added the `<input type="hidden" name="Chatroom" value={{key}}>` just above the submit button.And in the backend I request it like this `hidden_id = request.GET.get('Chatroom','')`. But when I print the hidden_id, it prints nothing. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Your form is using POST, not GET? So it should be `request.POST.get`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!!!!
I was stuck upon this from past 2 days, trying jquery and javascript. and you just solved it with just one line of code. Thanks man. Thumbs up.!!!!

Comment: @OptimusCrime- Can this be done with jQuery-Ajax? Actually the solution till now is kinda slow. it loads the whole page upon posting and receiving the reply. How this can be achieved with jQuery-Ajax.
Thanks